# Setting up my DHCP server, I am confused with the IP range

Tags: iptables, windows-server-2008, desktop-computer, dhcp-server

I am currently setting up my DHCP server, but I don't know what must the IP range be. And I keep getting this error:

[image: the instruction is the DHCP must assign my 3 PCs with 192.168.1.4-6]

Answer (score 1):

The subnet mask `255.255.255.0` means that your DHCP can only cover the ranges `192.168.0.2-254` or `192.168.1.2-254`, **but not both** (assuming `192.168.x.1` is reserved by your router, and `192.168.x.255` is reserved by the broadcast address).

The solution is to set `Starting IP address` to `192.168.1.4`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need 512 addresses on your network, then leave your addresses alone and fix the subnet mask:

```
 start addr: 192.168.000.1    <-- first address on the whole network
 dhcp start: 192.168.000.4    <--    can be any .0.2-.1.253
   end addr: 192.168.001.254  <-- last address on the whole network
  broadcast: 192.168.001.255
subnet mask: 255.255.254.0    <-- /23 network rather than /24
                     ^^^
```

For this to work properly you'll need to make sure your DHCP server is also using this subnet mask.  Check out http://www.subnetmask.info/ or similar tools.